How to correctly handle parsing errors with PetitParser or PetitParser2 in Pharo
I know there has been an old question How can a PetitParser parse rule signal an error?.  Lukas Renggli has written it is:

in general this is not good style (mixes syntactic and semantic
analysis)

My question is how to do it with more complex example correctly?
Here is my example:
I want to parse the following term:
(0.53,00)
     ^

I want to tell the user the error is where the ^ points.  Something like: "please remove the extra comma from your input".
The grammar is:
^ openParenthesis, number, closeParenthesis

The tokens:
openParenthesis
    ^ $( asPParser

number
    ^ wholeNumber plus, dot optional, wholeNumber optional

closeParenthesis
    ^ $) asPParser

wholeNumber 
   ^#digit asPParser plus trim

How would you write a code to detect such (additional comma) kind of error?

You can use the negative lookahead parser. I do not remember the API in Smalltalk, but in Dart (a direct port of the original Smalltalk implementation) you would write:
In Dart for comparison
final grammar = char('(') 
    & number 
    & char(',').not('please remove the extra comma from your input') 
    & char(')'); 

Original PetitParser in Smalltalk (as Lukas Renggli suggested in comments section)
To implement it in the original PetitParser (as suggested in comments):
Add message instance variable to the class definition:
PPDelegateParser subclass:#PPNotParser
        instanceVariableNames:'message'
        classVariableNames:''
        poolDictionaries:''
        category:'PetitParser-Parsers'

In the PPNotParser>>parseOn:
parseOn: aPPContext
        | element memento |
        memento := aPPContext remember.
        element := parser parseOn: aPPContext.
        aPPContext restore: memento.
        ^ element isPetitFailure
                ifFalse: [ PPFailure message: message context: aPPContext ]

Testing with PetitParser2
To do just testing in Pharo Smalltalk with PetitParser2 you have to do the following - to implement it as in PetitParser above would be probably harder:

Add #message to #PP2NotNode:

    PP2DelegateNode subclass: #PP2NotNode
       instanceVariableNames: 'message'
       classVariableNames: ''
       package: 'PetitParser2-Nodes'


Create setters and getters in #PP2NotNode

   message: aString
       message := aString
   message
       ^ message


Edit PP2NotNode>>#parseOn: and make decision based on if the message is empty or not:

parseOn: aPP2Context
    ^ self message isEmptyOrNil
        ifTrue: [ strategy parseOn: aPP2Context ]
        ifFalse: [ strategy parseOn: aPP2Context message: self message ]


Next create a new method PP2Not>>parseOn:message:

parseOn: context message: aMessageString
    | memento retval |
    memento := self remember: context.
    retval := node child parseOn: context.
    self restore: context from: memento.
    ^ retval isPetit2Failure
        ifTrue: [ nil ]
        ifFalse: [ PP2Failure message: aMessageString context: context ]


You have to enhance PP2CompositeNodeTest>>parse: production:to:end:checkResult:

parse: aString production: production to: expectedResult end: end checkResult: aBoolean
    | ctx |
    ctx := self context.
    resultContext := self
        parse: aString
        withParser: production
        withContext: ctx.
    result := resultContext value.
    resultContext isPetit2Failure
        ifTrue: [ self unableToParse: resultContext withString: aString ].
    self assert: resultContext position equals: end.
    aBoolean
        ifTrue: [ self assert: expectedResult equals: result ].
    ^ result


Last but not the least create a method PP2CompositeNodeTest>>unableToParse:withString:

unableToParse: aResultContext withString: aString
    aResultContext message isEmptyOrNil
        ifTrue: [ self deny: aResultContext isPetit2Failure description: 'Unable to parse ' , aString printString ]
        ifFalse: [ self
                deny: aResultContext isPetit2Failure
                description:
                    aResultContext message , ' While parsing: ' , aString printString , '; ' , ' See postion: '
                        , aResultContext position asString ]

This returns your error message if the number is followed by a comma, but otherwise lets the next parser deal with the rest in the sequence.

Thank you very much for you answer.  I'll adjust it to smalltalk (I don't have a clue about Dart) edit your answer with the adjusted code.  Is the negative lookahead parser the only way?  Because if the example gets even more complicated it can get complex.  I can ask different question for that.

Hmm the method #not is defined as ^ PP2NotNode on: self how do I send the message? And #not: is not there.

In the original PetitParser the error message of the PPNotParser is unfortunately not configurable and hardcoded to be an empty string. However, it can be easily changed by adding a message instance variable and creating the error with the contents of that variable: https://i.sstatic.net/6HnrePOB.png
